# Switching from Ubuntu Studio to vanilla Ubuntu

Tags: uninstall, desktop-environments

My laptop has Ubuntu Studio 22.04 but it’s a bit too much for the old AMD Turion64 system and barely runs so I am trying to remove all the Studio components, including all the extra fonts, to try it with regular vanilla Ubuntu.

To that end, I ran these commands but it still boots to Ubuntu Studio. Actually, it first booted to the regular Ubuntu desktop but with no icons or menu, then after a moment and all by itself, the screen went black and Ubuntu Studio’s desktop reappeared. How do I get rid of it once and for all?

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get purge ubuntustudio-desktop
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntustudio-desktop
```

That does remove a tiny metapackage only.

After installing `ubuntu-desktop`, log out then log in on the standard Ubuntu desktop. From that point onwards, there is no automatic way to granularly remove packages from the ubuntu-studio desktop: you will need to inspect the installed packages and remove these that are not a dependency of components of the `ubuntu-desktop`.

The only way to have a clean slate is to do a default, fresh installation of the standard Ubuntu version.

Comment: It appears that a full re-install is needed as only one of the several desktops it has on it will work properly. Most simply reboot themselves over and over while the single working one has no WiFi (the others do for the brief time they are on). I’m not a newbie to Ubuntu and have been using it since the versions were still single-digit and have never seen problems like these before. For reinstallation, I’ll probably go for a lighter version such as Xubuntu that I hope will be a better match for this old and rarely used laptop.